# What's the minimum occupied space that triggers Windows' low space notification?

Tags: windows-8.1, ntfs, disk-space, storage

Is it a percentage related to the partition size? Or, is it a hard-fixed number?

What if it's a non-system partition? Why would it matter to Windows if it isn't installed into it?

In my case, I run Windows 8.1

Comment: This information has not been published by Microsoft

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Win8.1 but Windows XP and 7 notify the user when

- less than  200 MB
- less than  80 MB
- less than  50 MB
- 0 MB

of free space is left

Answer (score 2):

## Disk space checks

> Windows Vista polled available disk space every minute while Windows 7 does this every 10 minutes. This is designed for performance reasons and there is no likelihood of causing an unrecoverable problem to the Operating System or to your hardware.
>
> This would be any fixed or external hard drives (USB, eSATA, 1394/FireWire). When this polling occurs, Windows 7 will pop up with a notification at the following thresholds:
>
> - Free space less than 200 MB
> - Free space less than 80 MB
> - Free space less than 50 MB
> - Free space equals zero
>
> Windows 7 does not poll Zip Drives, Floppies or any other "removable" media drives.
>
> <sub>Source: [The low disk space notification message might be delayed up to 10 minutes in Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2547929/en-us)</sub>

I couldn't find any official articles regarding Windows 8.x, but I assume things aren't any different than Windows 7. Apparently there's no way to tweak the threshold values or the polling interval, and you can't exclude specific disks/partitions either.

Comment: Just to be sure, this notice also applies to a disk without Windows installed?

Comment: @Karolinger Yes. In Windows 7 and earlier this feature can be disabled, but I'm not sure whether the method still applies to Windows 8.x.